# Why is the onDraw Not Being Called in Custom View for Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, ondraw

I am developing in Android `Canvas`.

But the `onDraw()` has not called after `invalidate();`

In the **layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.wen.MainActivity">

    <com.wen.Drawpath_view
        android:id="@+id/view_path"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the **`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Drawpath_view View_path;
    private Button test_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View_path = findViewById(R.id.view_path);
        View_path = new Drawpath_view(MainActivity.this);

        test_btn = findViewById(R.id.test);
        test_btn.setOnClickListener(this);



        View_path.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {

                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

                View_path.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
               View_path.setMinimumHeight(View_path.getHeight());
                View_path.setMinimumWidth(View_path.getWidth());

                return true;

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.test){

            View_path.Testdraw();

        }
    }
}
```

In the customer `View`.

```
    public class Drawpath_view extends View {

        private static final String TAG = "view";
        private Paint paint;
        private Path path = new Path();

        public Drawpath_view(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            initView();
        }

        public Drawpath_view(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }


        private void initView() {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        }

        public void Testdraw(){
            Log.d(TAG,"draw");
            path.moveTo(60,60);
            path.lineTo(460,460);
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onDraw");
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        }
    }
```

When I click the button in Activity. It will call

```
        View_path.Testdraw();
```

But the `onDraw` in `Drawpath_view` has not been called. Did I missing something ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove View_path = new Drawpath_view(MainActivity.this); from your code, 
as you already attached view in xml.

Comment: Thanks! Save my day! :)

Comment: I don't understand. If he doesn't call new Drawpath_view(), how does the private method initView() ever get called? What if his constructor passed other parameters as well? Thanks for any clarification, because I am having the same problem!

Comment: I should add that by doing as you stated, the onDraw was called, and I did not need the setWillNotDraw(). But I had to make setters for fields I originally passed in the constructor. Is one not allowed to have a constructor in a custom view?

Answer (score 3):

By default all `ViewGroup` sub-classes do not call their `onDraw` method, you will enable it by calling `setWillNotDraw(false)` on `View_path`.

Comment: I have call `setWillNotDraw(false);` in `public Drawpath_view(Context context)`. But it is not working.

Comment: Remove  View_path = new Drawpath_view(MainActivity.this); from your code, as you already attached view in xml.

Comment: @Cansel, why do you have two answers?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `setWillNotDraw(false); initView();`
 into the second constructor as well.